How to bump python package version using uv?
Poetry has the version command to increment a package version. Does uv package manager has anything similar?

See this issue also

Currently uv package manager does not have a built-in command to bump package versions like poetry's version command. You can manually edit pyproject.toml or automate it with a script.
For example:
import toml
from typing import Literal

def bump_version(file_path: str, part: Literal["major", "minor", "patch"] = "patch") -> None:
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        pyproject = toml.load(f)

    version = pyproject["tool"]["poetry"]["version"]
    major, minor, patch = map(int, version.split("."))

    if part == "major":
        major += 1
        minor = 0
        patch = 0
    elif part == "minor":
        minor += 1
        patch = 0
    elif part == "patch":
        patch += 1
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid part value. Choose 'major', 'minor', or 'patch'.")

    pyproject["tool"]["poetry"]["version"] = f"{major}.{minor}.{patch}"

    with open(file_path, "w") as f:
        toml.dump(pyproject, f)

    print(f"Version bumped to {major}.{minor}.{patch}")


I do this:
uvx --from=toml-cli toml set --toml-path=pyproject.toml project.version $VERSION

If you need to retrieve:
uvx --from=toml-cli toml get --toml-path=pyproject.toml project.version

Works in a Dockerfile, makefile, etc
